# Set up Beagleboard emulator with qemu in Ubuntu

Tags: arm, qemu, beagleboard, linaro

To setup qemu for Beagleboard in Ubuntu 14.04, I am following steps given in link below:

http://www.cnx-software.com/2011/09/26/beagleboard-emulator-in-ubuntu-with-qemu/

When I tried to run ALIP image in qemu by command :

```
sudo qemu-system-arm -M beagle -m 256 -drive file=./beagle_sd_alip_x11.img,if=sd,cache=writeback -clock unix -serial stdio -device usb-kbd -device usb-mouse
```

I got following error :

```
qemu-system-arm: -M beagle: Unsupported machine type
Use -machine help to list supported machines!
```

How can I fix this error ?

PS:

1. I am new to Beagleboard and Qemu environment.
2. I am trying to understand Userspace Arduino Libraries for Beagleboard.More details about it can be found here: http://elinux.org/Userspace_Arduino .It would be great if anyone can guide to test example codes like blinking led, 7 segment display etc.from Userspace Arduino in Qemu.

Comment: That tutorial appears to predate [Ubuntu providing their own `qemu-system` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=qemu-system&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) - are you sure you installed the Linaro package and not Ubuntu's one? (BeagleBoard support isn't in mainline QEMU, which the more recent Ubuntu packages look to be of)

Comment: @Notlikethat : Yeah, I installed Linaro package only. This error comes when I try to run beagleboard image.

Comment: what is the output of `qemu-system-arm -machine help` ?

Comment: List of supported machines in which beagle or beaglexm is not there.

Answer (score 11):

You can build qemu with beagleboard support yourself with these steps, which I have tried with Ubuntu 14.04.

First remove the qemu package that you have installed with

`$ sudo apt-get remove qemu-system-arm`

Then download the source code for qemu to a suitable folder

`$ git clone git://git.linaro.org/qemu/qemu-linaro.git
 $ cd qemu-linaro`

You need these two packages to build qemu

`$ sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev zlib1g-dev`

You will also need the pixman and dtc git submodules

`$ git submodule update --init pixman
 $ git submodule update --init dtc`

Now you can continue and configure and build it!

`$ mkdir build
 $ cd build
 $ ../configure --prefix=/opt
 $ make -j8
 $ sudo make install`

The qemu-system-arm executable can be found in /opt/bin. Add this to your path if you haven't already and you´re good to go.

Comment: How to get rid of `error: ‘g_mem_set_vtable’ is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]`... `make -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -j8` did not work

Comment: try "$ ../configure --prefix=/opt --disable-werror" instead of "$ ../configure --prefix=/opt"

Comment: If someone tries this today and gets errors for major or minor being undefined, `#include <sys/sysmacros.h>` in `virtio-9p.h`. Also, there are plenty of things that can be disabled to make it compile faster - for example `../configure --python=/usr/bin/python2 --disable-werror --target-list=aarch64-softmmu,arm-softmmu --disable-vnc --disable-xen --disable-guest-agent --disable-bluez --disable-docs --disable-rdma --disable-vde --disable-libiscsi --disable-libnfs --disable-tpm --disable-libssh2 --disable-vhdx`