# How to setup Beaglebone black for qemu and kvm on ubuntu?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, qemu, kvm

Hello I was trying to configure beaglebone black (AM335x) for qemu. So that we can test our designs before testing on actual hardware. But while Googling I don't find any solution about it.
Any one here to help me out?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35447029/qemu-with-beaglebone-support